# Prevent Swashbuckle from setting "Accept" header

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I have a .NET 7 Web API project in which I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` to produce a Swagger UI.

One of my endpoints can return a different `Content-Type` value depending on the response status code; `application/xml` for a 200 and `application/json` for a 404.

I've managed to get the Swagger UI to convey this by decorating the controller method with `SwaggerResponse` attributes, such that the example response for a 200 shows as XML and the example response for a 404 shows as JSON. So far so good.

The problem comes when I actually invoke the endpoint from the Swagger UI. The response is always XML, even for a 404. I called the same endpoint in Postman and to my surprise, saw different behaviour - JSON for a 404 rather than XML. I then realised what's happening: the Swagger UI is passing an `Accept` header with a content type of `application/xml`, so it's basically doing content negotiation.

Looking more closely at the Swagger, this is made clear where it says "Controls Accept header" next to the first example response:

[image]

My question is: is it possible to change this behaviour so that Swashbuckle doesn't automatically pass an Accept header?

#### Minimal code example to repro the issue

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.EnableAnnotations());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

WeatherForecastController.cs:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        [Produces("application/xml", "application/json")]
        [SwaggerResponse(200, Type = typeof(XDocument), ContentTypes = new[] { "application/xml" })]
        [SwaggerResponse(404, Type = typeof(ProblemDetails), ContentTypes = new[] { "application/json" })]
        public ActionResult<WeatherForecast> Get(string region)
        {
            if (region is not "Yorkshire")
            {
                return this.NotFound();
            }

            var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();

            var doc = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            {
                // write xml into the writer
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(forecast.GetType());
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, forecast);
            }

            return this.Content(doc.ToString(), "application/xml");
        }
    }
}
```

WeatherForecast.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got your point from your comment

You may try with a filter:

```
public class AddContentTypeFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var responses= operation.Responses;
        foreach(var response in responses)
        {
            response.Value.Content.Add("*/*", new OpenApiMediaType() );
        }
    }
}
```

Apply it:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.OperationFilter<AddContentTypeFilter>());
```

Now you could select  the option for 200 Result

[image]

It would allow all content types

For 404:

[image]

For 200:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look at this. You're right that it's caused by the presence of the `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter`. I've added a minimal example to the question as requested.

Comment: Ideally I would still like to know if Swashbuckle can be configured to not automatically pass an Accept request header based on the media type associated with the first example response.

Comment: I got what you mean,it's hard to prevent it from setting the header (which would be done in js),but we could add an option that we accepet all content-types ,I've updated my answer,hopes help